# NSFetchedResultsController Not Auto-Updating the collection View

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I have a didPressSend function which takes in the text that was written in a textview and inserts it into context as a String. Once inserted into context, NSFetchedResultsController's DidChangeContent detects that something was inserted into context and auto-updates the collection View accordingly (Keep in mind that DidChangeContent is absolutely empty). Here is the code I have just for that part. (Create message with text is the function that inserts into context).

```
 func didPressSendButton(button: UIButton!, withMessageText text: String!, senderId: String! ,senderDisplayName: String!, date: NSDate){

    let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext



   createMessageWithText(text, friend: friend!, context: moc, date: date)



    do {
        try context.save()


    } catch let err {
        print(err)
    }


}
private func createMessageWithText(text: String, friend: Friend, context: NSManagedObjectContext, date: NSDate, isSender: Bool = false) -> Mesages {
    let message = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Mesages", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! Mesages

    message.user = friend
    message.text = text
    message.timestamp = date
    message.isSender = isSender
    friend.lastMessage = message


    return message

}
```

}

Once inserted into context, the didChangeContent detects it as such and auto-updates the collection view  :

```
lazy var fetchedResultsControler: NSFetchedResultsController = {



    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Mesages")
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 50
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "timestamp", ascending: true)]
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "user.id = %@", self.friend!.id!)
    let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    frc.delegate = self
    return frc
}()



func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {

}
```

The weird part is, there is absolutely nothing in DidChangeContent that seems to be responsible for populating the collectionView, keep in mind that I'm populating the collectionView with the number of objects in the fetchResultsController as such :

```
  override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) ->

    Int {
        if let count = fetchedResultsControler.sections?[0].numberOfObjects {
            return count
        }
        return 0
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


    let cell = super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath) as! JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell
    return cell
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageData! {


    let msg : Mesages = fetchedResultsControler.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Mesages
    let messageData = JSQMessage(senderId: "" , displayName: "Me", text: msg.text)
    return messageData


}
```

I also have a listener from firebase, which, whenever a message is sent to me, it detects it right away, inserts into context, saves, nsfetchResultsController detects that, and didChangeContent is triggered. The weird part is, it does not auto-update in that case unless I put collectionView.reloadData in didChangeContent, However I do not need to put collectionView.reloadData for didPressSend, as it magically auto-updates on its own. The code for the firebase listener which inserts into context the same way that didPressSend does is the following:  (Create message with text is the function that inserts into context).

```
ref2.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {(snapshot2) in
            let messageId = snapshot2.key
            //first message ID out of 20.
            let messagesRef =     FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("messages").child(messageId)
            messagesRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in



                let dictionary = snapshot.value as! [NSObject: AnyObject]

                let timestamp = dictionary["timestamp"] as! NSNumber
                let doubleTimestamp = Double(timestamp)

                let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: (doubleTimestamp))








                    self.createMessageWithText(dictionary["text"]! as! String, friend: friend, context: context, date: date, isSender: true)





                do {
                    try context.save()

                }

                catch {
                    print(error)

                }



   private func createMessageWithText(text: String, friend: Friend, context: NSManagedObjectContext, date: NSDate, isSender: Bool = false) -> Mesages {
    let message = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Mesages", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! Mesages

    message.user = friend
    message.text = text
    message.timestamp = date
    message.isSender = isSender
    friend.lastMessage = message


    return message

}
```

That said, I'm not sure why and how the collectionView is being populated with NSfetchedResultsController. (It really concerns me that DidPressSend is populating the collection View without ANY reload data of any sort). Also ANOTHER bug that comes with this, if I remove didChangeContent, which as you can see contains NOTHING, didPressSend stops auto-updating. And when I add the empty didChangeContent, the collection View starts auto-updating (only for didpressSend).

Comment: It is normal for tracking to be enabled and for the table view to be updated automatically if the fetchedResultsController has a delegate set and `controllerDidChangeContent` exists (even if it is empty).

Comment: For Firebase, are you sure the data is inserted in the same context or in the same thread? That could explain why the update is not triggered...

Comment: See the "important" section in Apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008227-CH1-SW17

Answer (score 0):

Implement below delegate method, and collectionView or TableView will update sync. as soon as get new data.

```
extension ViewController: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
  }
}
```